# Proving the invertibility of a matrix (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove the following statement or give a counterexample if it is false.

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. If there exists a  $b\in\mathbb R^{n}$ such that $Ax=b$ has a unique solution then $A$ is invertible.

What i tried:

We can see that there exists a $b=0$ such that the equation becomes $Ax=0$ and the unique solution is the trival solution $x=0$, hence $A$ is invertible since only the trival solution exists.

Is my proof correct? Also is this question the contrapositive to the theorem in this question:

[Proving the existence of an inverse of a matrix. (Linear algebra)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418693/proving-the-existence-of-an-inverse-of-a-matrix-linear-algebra).

Beacuse if it is i could use the same method to solve it?

Comment: yes, but I think "If there exists a  $b∈R^{n}$ such that $Ax=b$ has a unique solution then $A$ is invertible" have to be for every  $b∈R^{n}$ ....

Comment: @RaziehNoori No, it is enough to demand that a single such $b$ exists.

Comment: And yeah is this question the contrapostive to the theorem in this question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418693/proving-the-existence-of-an-inverse-of-a-matrix-linear-algebra If so i could have used the same method to solve it.

Comment: @5xum may I know how?

Comment: @RaziehNoori Take $y$ such that $Ay=0$ and $x$ such that $Ax=0$. Then, $A(x+y) = \dots$.

Comment: Then $A(x+y)=b$ Am i correct?

Comment: i think you mean is if for that special $b$, $x$ be answer and $Ax=0$ then $A(x+y)=b$ and uniqness will give $x+y=x$ hence $y=0$

Comment: excellent @5xum very vey good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. Your proof would be correct if the statement was

> If for every $b\in\mathbb R^n$, the equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, then $A$ is invertible.

But you don't have that. You have one specific vector $b$ for which there exists a single $x$ such that $Ax = b$.

My **hint**:

Take any $y$ such that $Ay = 0$ and see what $A(x+y)$ is.

---

Also, your statement is **not** the contraposition of the linked question. The linked question states

> If $A$ is not invertible, then there exists some $b$ such that $Ax=b$ has no solution.

The contraposition of this is (since $p\implies q$ is contraposed as $\neg q \implies \neg p$)

> If there exists no $b$ such that $Ax=b$ has no solution, then it is not true that $A$ is not invertible

Getting rid of double negations, that would mean that the contraposition is

> If for all $b$, the equation $Ax=b$ has some solution, then $A$ is invertible.

Which is different than the statement you have here.