# What does determinant (of $3\times 3$ matrix) =0 mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

Given three normalized vectors
$$
\mathbf{u}=(\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \mathbf{u}_3)
$$
$$
\mathbf{v}=(\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3)
$$
$$
\mathbf{w}=(\mathbf{w}_1, \mathbf{w}_2, \mathbf{w}_3)
$$
$$
||\mathbf{u}||=||\mathbf{v}||=||\mathbf{w}||=1
$$
What does

$$
\det\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2& \mathbf{u}_3 \\
\mathbf{v}_1& \mathbf{v}_2& \mathbf{v}_3\\
\mathbf{w}_1& \mathbf{w}_2& \mathbf{w}_3
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
mean (geometrical interpretation) ?

I also find out that
$$
\det\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2& \mathbf{u}_3 \\
\mathbf{v}_1& \mathbf{v}_2& \mathbf{v}_3\\
\mathbf{w}_1& \mathbf{w}_2& \mathbf{w}_3
\end{vmatrix}=
\det\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_3& \mathbf{u}_1 \\
\mathbf{w}_2& \mathbf{w}_3& \mathbf{w}_1\\
\mathbf{v}_2& \mathbf{v}_3& \mathbf{v}_1\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
what's the geometrical implication of this equation?

Answer (score 1):

$\det\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2& \mathbf{u}_3 \\
\mathbf{v}_1& \mathbf{v}_2& \mathbf{v}_3\\
\mathbf{w}_1& \mathbf{w}_2& \mathbf{w}_3
\end{bmatrix}=0 \iff \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Do you mean two of the three vectors lie in the same plane?

Comment: @whitegreen No, all the three vectors lie in the same plane.

Answer (score 1):

I think 3Blue1Brown's video about the determinant will be useful for you: https://youtu.be/Ip3X9LOh2dk

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, it means the [parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) whose sides are $u,v,w$ has zero volume. This, in turn, means the parallelepiped is "flat", or contained in a single plane.

For more details and equivalent statements, see these popular questions with their many answers:

[What's an intuitive way to think about the determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668)
[What does it mean to have a determinant equal to zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/355644)